# IndexedDB: Data is stored in the wrong table

Tags: javascript, memcached, browser-cache, indexeddb

In my app, there are two processes for manipulating the db library: the first is the polling task, which is used to schedule the data from Table A to the server side, and the second is to store the data in Table B when the user clicks on the menu. But the end result is that the data that should have been deposited on Form B is stored in Form A. I suspect that two processes are the cause of concurrent occurrence, but this phenomenon cannot be repeated. I would like to ask what circumstances will cause this to happen （Table represents the objectstore in IndexedDB IndexedDB API）

```
export function IDBSaveData(data, dbTableName){
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let name = dbTableName ? dbTableName : 'A';
    var tx = db.transaction(name,'readwrite');
    var store = tx.objectStore(name);
    var req = store.put(data);
    let returnData = '', result = false;
    req.onsuccess = function(){
        returnData = this.result
        result = true
    }
    req.onerror = function(e){
        returnData = e.target.result
    }
    tx.oncomplete = function(){
        if (result) {
            console.log('success save');
            resolve(true)
        } else {
            console.log('save error！');
            reject(returnData)
        }
    }
    tx.onerror = function(){
        console.log(returnData.error)
        reject(returnData)
    }
})
}
```

The polling task:

```
setTimeout(async ()=>{
   let json = await DBSearchData('B'); // Query Table A data
     for(let i=0,i<json.length;i++){
       // ... Asynchronous operations
       await DBSaveData(json[i], 'C') // Put this piece of data into Table C
       await DBDeleteData(json[i], 'B') // Delete this piece of data from Table B
     }
}, 10000)
```

user clicks on the menu:

```
IDBSaveData(data, 'A')
```

The above code is my method of putting data into IndexedDB, and I checked my code and there was no error in the table name that was passed in when the method was called.

Comment: What sets `dbTableName`? Please post more of the relevant code.

Comment: It's already been added. Arguments passed in when a method is called

Comment: Can you please clarify what arguments are passed in when the method is called? For example, can you describe and/or show the code that calls the method, and specifically describe how that calling code sets `dbTableName`?

Comment: The general flow of the calling method has been added, I think there should be no errors here, I do not know if it is a concurrent operation of the error

Comment: Where do you ever call `IDBSaveData` while passing a second paramter that is some other value than A or undefined?

Comment: There are only three places in my program that call this method, and there are two forms of incoming parameters, one with a specific table name and the other undefined. In the calling method is the incoming argument, as I mentioned above, there should be no problem